# Logging in using Python 3

Tags: cookies, authentication, python-3.x

How to login to a site say http://www.example.com/ given I have a username and a password and retreive Cookies for further usage in Python 3?

Comment: It depends on how the website is processing the form input, username and password.

Comment: say it's http://en.wikipedia.org/

Comment: Learn what is an HTML form, read the HTML of the login page of the site you're interested in to see how the form looks and which HTTP method it uses, and send the appropriate headers (and body, if necessary) in the request. Nobody's going to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet I used in python to log into a web page:

```
base_url = "http://www.example.com"
store = 01234
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'

post_data = {
        'hdnAction': 'LOGIN',
        'txtStoreID': '%s' % store,
        'txtLogin': '%s' % username,
        'txtpassword': '%s' % password,
        'txtNumLines':'10',
        'btnLogin':'Login',
        'hdnCount':'0'
}
params = urllib.urlencode(post_data)
request = urllib2.Request(base_url + "/", params)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
#print "getting url: %s" % request.get_full_url()
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, params, 300)
xmldata = response.read()
redirects = re.compile('''window\.location\.href="(.*?)"''', re.DOTALL).findall(xmldata)
cookie = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie').split(';')[0].strip() + ";"
if len(redirects) > 0 :
    request = urllib2.Request(base_url + "%s" % redirects[0])
    print "getting url: %s" % request.get_full_url()
    request.add_header('cookie', cookie)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request, None, 300)
    xmldata = response.read()
```

Those things in post data are elements on the HTML FORM tag. Look at thier "name" attributes.